# The most time/space efficient way to list all indices in an object

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am looking for 2 algorithms for creating a list of all indices in a string/list/etc.

I am not familiar with how range works. It is my understanding that using range creates an additional list in memory, and this is what I am trying to avoid here.

- The most time efficient algorithm
- The most space efficient algorithm

My code for optimal time:

```
string = 'sentence'
indices = []
for i in range(len(string)):
    indices.append(i)
```

My code for optimal space:

```
string = 'sentence'
indices = []
string_len = len(string)
i = 0
while i < string_len:
    indices.append(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3, to begin with?

Comment: @Dolda2000 I am using 2.7 because I like the IDE Spyder, but would be interested in knowing if 3 has some advantage here.

Comment: 1) You are optimizing the unimportant parts. 2) `range(len(thing))` is already the list you want.

Comment: @mattkaeo: It doesn't have any advantages here, but it matters for how functions like `range()` work.

Comment: Do you also need the original element along with the index?

Comment: @user2357112 I am not familiar with how range works. It was my understanding that using range creates an additional list in memory.

Comment: @mattkaeo: Doing `indices = range(len(string))` creates only one list all at once, while your first code snippet creates a list, slowly builds up another list, and then discards the first list.

Comment: @mattkaeo: If you just write `indices = range(len(string))`, there is no "additional" list.  There is only a single list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimal time *and* space:

```
string = 'sentence'
indices = range(len(string))        # Python 2
indices = list(range(len(string)))  # Python 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think the most time-, space- and code-efficient way to do this would be this:

```
string = "sentence"
indices = range(len(string))
```

Also, for the record, if you replace `range()` with `xrange()` in your first suggestion, it is just as space-efficient as the second, since `xrange()` is lazy.